# Anylogic agent animation

Tags: animation, nodes, move, anylogic, agent

I am currently working on a simple animation in which trucks initially positionned at a node  called 'home' travel through a path to a rectangular node to load materials. The problem that occurs when I start the simulation, is that trucks are not positioned initially inside the home node but rather appear from the upper left side of the simulation window and move through the home node and then to the loading area. I have tried everthing to catch the source of the problem but haven't figured out what is causing this.

Has anyone run into a similar issue?

Comment: Where did you set the arrival location for the trucks?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jumpTo() in the on startup field of main.
In [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiB1h.jpg) case there is 1 truck named truck and on startup of the model it jumps to the given node by using:

```
truck.jumpTo(node)
```

Alternatively you could let trucks arrive via a sourceblock and just specify the arrival location in this block.

Good luck!